# Problem loading a GeoJSON file using Openlayers

Tags: openlayers-2, geojson

I am setting up a website using Openlayers and GeoJSON files.  When I get the GeoJSON file using the code below it work as expected.

```
url: "./file.geojson",
```

But if I try and use the full domain call, see below, it does not work.  Why?

```
url: "http://www.domain.com/file.geojson",
```

I need to use the full domain call because I am trying to test it locally on my computer.  Is there a way to get the file locally from my computer?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

var lon = -80.233,
            lat = 40.665,
            zoom = 15,
            epsg4326 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:4326'),
            epsg900913 = new OpenLayers.Projection('EPSG:900913');
        var arrayAerial;
        var select;

```
    function init(){
        var map = new OpenLayers.Map('map', {
            units: 'm',
            numZoomLevels: 19,
            controls: [
                new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.MousePosition(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.LayerSwitcher(),
                //new OpenLayers.Control.OverviewMap(),
                new OpenLayers.Control.PanZoomBar()
            ],
            projection: epsg900913,
            displayProjection: epsg4326 //Is used for displaying coordinates in appropriate CRS by MousePosition control
        });






        arrayOSM = ["http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/map/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg"];


        arrayAerial = ["http://otile1.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile2.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile3.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg",
                    "http://otile4.mqcdn.com/tiles/1.0.0/sat/${z}/${x}/${y}.jpg"];

        baseOSM = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MapQuest-OSM Tiles", arrayOSM);                        
        baseAerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("MapQuest Open Aerial Tiles", arrayAerial);

        var sanpipe_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("San Sewer", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    fillColor: "#2da725",
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeColor: "#2da725",
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),

                }),

            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./sanpipe.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

        var mh_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Manholes", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    fillColor: "#9de24f",
                    strokeColor: "#0d4cd6",
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),

                }),

            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./mh.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON({
                    extractAttributes: true
                })
            })
        });

        var waterline_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("waterline", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    fillColor: "#00FF01",
                    fillOpacity: 0.8,
                    strokeColor: "#0d4cd6",
                    strokeWidth: 3,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),

                }),

            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./waterline.geojson",
                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

        var valves_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Valves", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 3,
                    fillColor: "#fdf700",
                    strokeColor: "#0d4cd6",
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),

                }),

            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./valves.geojson",

                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

        var hyd_layer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Vector("Hydrants", {
            styleMap: new OpenLayers.StyleMap({
                    "default": new OpenLayers.Style({
                    pointRadius: 5,
                    fillColor: "#d81417",
                    strokeColor: "#0d4cd6",
                    strokeWidth: 1,
                    strokeOpacity: 0.8 } ),

                }),

            projection: epsg4326,
            strategies: [new OpenLayers.Strategy.Fixed()],
            protocol: new OpenLayers.Protocol.HTTP({
                url: "./hyd.geojson",

                format: new OpenLayers.Format.GeoJSON()
            })
        });

        map.addLayer(baseOSM);
        map.addLayer(baseAerial);
        map.addLayer(sanpipe_layer);
        map.addLayer(mh_layer);
        map.addLayer(waterline_layer);
        map.addLayer(valves_layer);
        map.addLayer(hyd_layer);

        select = new OpenLayers.Control.SelectFeature(mh_layer);

        mh_layer.events.on({
            "featureselected": onFeatureSelect,
            "featureunselected": onFeatureUnselect
        });

        map.addControl(select);
        select.activate();  

        map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(lon, lat).transform(epsg4326, epsg900913), zoom);
    }

    function onPopupClose(evt) {
        select.unselectAll();
    }
    function onFeatureSelect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        popup = new OpenLayers.Popup.FramedCloud("chicken", 
            feature.geometry.getBounds().getCenterLonLat(),
            null,
            "<h2>"+feature.attributes.STRUCT_ID + "</h2>",
            null, true, onPopupClose);

        feature.popup = popup;
        map.addPopup(popup);
    }

    function onFeatureUnselect(event) {
        var feature = event.feature;
        if(feature.popup) {
            map.removePopup(feature.popup);
            feature.popup.destroy();
            delete feature.popup;
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Do you have a proxy setup?  This could be a javascript same domain issue?  What does firebug (or other inspector) show?

Comment: No I don't have a proxy setup.  Firebug does not show the variable containing the url parameter?  FYI, I am a novice when it comes to webservers, openlayers, and javascript.

Comment: Checkout the firebug network tab. It will likely tell you that you are or are not actually pulling the geojson.

Comment: It is not listed in the network tab.

Comment: That suggests to me that the call is never happening.  Can you post the full openlayers code?

Comment: Sorry it took so long to upload the code.

Comment: Cross domain policy doesn't allow access to files in different host/port, you have to set up proxy. There are plenty of postings both here in stackexchange and in Google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the file properly, you need to follow these steps:

1. Always use a webserver to host your own files. These kinds of calls will not be made if your browser is opening the html using the file protocol.
2. If in your url (`http://www.domain.com/file.geojson`) the domain is not the same as the domain of your webserver, JavaScript cannot directly access the data. Due to Javascript security rules, you are not allowed to make an XMLHttpRequest to another server. For example, if you have your openlayers application running off your webserver, and you are accessing it as `http://localhost/map.html`, the JavaScript won't be able to access an location such as `http://www.example.com/file.geojson`.

   In this case you will be required to use a proxy.  The [OpenLayers FAQ](http://trac.osgeo.org/openlayers/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#ProxyHost) has a section on setting up your own ProxyHost. Here's the relevant excerpt:

> **How do I set up a ProxyHost?**
>
> An example proxy host script is available here:
> trunk/openlayers/examples/proxy.cgi
>
> For the standard Apache configuration, you would place proxy.cgi into
> your /usr/lib/cgi-bin/ directory.
>
> Once a proxy host script has been installed, you must then edit the
> OpenLayers.ProxyHost variable to match that URL.
>
> Given the above standard Apache configuration:
>
> OpenLayers.ProxyHost = "/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi?url=";
>
> If you have done something like this, you should be able to visit:
>
> http://YourDomain.example.com/cgi-bin/proxy.cgi
>
> The resulting content at that page should be the openlayers.org
> website.
>
> If you get a 404 error instead, either the proxy script is not in the
> right location, or your webserver is not configured correctly.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is because of the geojson extension is not allowed on your server. the simplest way change your .geojson file extension to .json then it's work. 
the essential solution is define .geojson in your server.